# Is it possible to change a JScrollPane to a TreeModel in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

I need to add a scroll bar to `DefaultMutableTreeNode` or `DefaultTreeMode`.

It would be more helpful if you could suggest something other than this:

```
tree = new JTree(systemModel);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
```

Comment: Neither `DefaultMutableTreeNode` nor `DefaultTreeModel` can get a scroll bar directly. Scroll bar can get only the visual component but not a model (or part of the model). I would suggest, you simply take the standard example from the page [How to use trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and try to play with it.

Comment: Actually my issue here is I had used JScrollPane to add a scroll bar,but my treemodel has 3 subcomponents which i am populating it to a tree and then populating tree to JScrollPane

Comment: In this Case I could notice that Scroll bar is added only to the first component of a treeModel and rest doesnt have,But Yes when the nodes are not in expanded form for the first time I could see the scroll bar in all 3 components but on click of second and third component for the second time the scroll bar disappears.